# Google Analytics 4 API (runReport) - Is it possible to add delta between two dateRanges values?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I was reading through the entire docs, browsing the web, but I couldn't find this thing anywhere so I come here as a last resort.
Namely, I'm trying to use the `runReport` API, and I need the Delta of 1 date range value vs second date range value. I know I could do this in a script, but I'd prefer doing it in the API request itself to get more consistent results.
My payload looks like:

```
{
  "metrics": [
    {
      "name": "totalUsers"
    },
    {
      "name": "screenPageViews"
    },
    {
      "name": "sessions"
    },
    {
      "name": "newUsers"
    },
    {
      "name": "engagedSessions"
    }
  ],
  "dateRanges": [
    {
      "startDate": "2023-05-16",
      "endDate": "2023-06-16",
      "name": "curr_period"
    },
    {
      "name": "prev_period",
      "startDate": "2023-04-15",
      "endDate": "2023-05-15"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is the API I'm hitting:
`POST https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/{xxxxxxx}:runReport`